# IIS Site with Anonymous authentication and WCF service in the same domain with Basic authentication is it possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, sitecore9

I am having a Site in IIS and I have a WCF service which is hosted within this site. I want the site to have a anonymous authentication and Service to have basic authentication. I tried but when I am giving the user name and password it is not redirecting anywhere and still asking for it. Is anyone faced the same kind of problem?

Comment: https://forums.iis.net/t/1163075.aspx?File+Specific+Authentication+Settings+

Comment: try to check the following document.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-services-and-aspnet

Answer (score 0):

So, after lot of struggles i finally found the problem.

```
<authentication mode="None">
  <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
</authentication>
```

Authentication mode was set to None the moment i changes to Windows i am able to go login it opens the service.

Thanks for the support.